# How to update assemblies for biztalk applications

Tags: biztalk, gac

Usually we need to modfiy the code for new requirements, then rebuild the project and gac the dll files modfied on the biztalk server, that way works fine before last month. Now I find that's not enough, I have to add the dll files mannully by 'Add resource' and then everything goes well as before. I got no idea about that as I took over the biztalk 2006 project rencently but I know nothing about that before.
I read the ms document [How to Add a BizTalk Assembly to an Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa558703.aspx), I found a problem when excute 'BTSTask AddResource /ApplicationName:MyApplication /Type:System.BizTalk:BizTalkAssembly /Overwrite /Source:"C:\BizTalk Assemblies\MyOrchestration.dll" /Destination:"C:\New BizTalk Assemblies\ MyOrchestration.dll "', an error prompt that I must unenlist the orchestrations before add the assmebly just like what I do 'Add resource' manully.
**Is there a way to add modfied dll files by just using 'gacutil.exe /i' as I do before?**

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not you can "sneak" a new Assembly in depends on several factors.  However, in no cases is this a supported production operation.

If only the internals of an Artifact have changed, Schemas and Maps being the least complicating, you can usually get away with it, in DEV only.  But if any interface (Ports) or definitions (Schema/Message Type) changes, you have to remove and redeploy.

So, sorry to say, but you've probably just been lucky up to now.

Comment: Thank u for your answer! But do u read the page " How to Add a BizTalk Assembly to an Application"? There seems to be no dout that we can add modified assemblies(dll files rebuilded as changes in such as schema/MessageType/Port changes ) in official way, the offical documents tells us we can do that regardless of DEV,ITG or PRO environment and in fact, we have done like that for years. My point is how to simplify the process, can u share your idea?

Comment: Ah, to clarify, when I say "sneak", I specifically mean by updating the GAC only and *not* using one of the BizTalk Deployment mechanisms, BT Admin, BTSTask or Visual Studio.  There is no way around the requirement to Unenlist an Orchestration before updating it's Assembly in a supported way.